# localhost server not found

Tags: php

When I execute script on my local host for `file_get_contents($url)` it keep loading for few minutes then displays this error:

```
Server not found

Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com.
```

any help?

Comment: Are you sure your XAMPP (or whatever you're using) is running?

Comment: Have you set address of www.localhost.com in `hosts` file ? If not just use `http://localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your script doing? Is your server (for example apache) started and in firefox you launched url

```
http://localhost/
```

? It seems firefox is looking another domain and not real localhost

Put this code in your php file (only this code):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.yelp.com';

$output = file_get_contents($url);

var_dump($output);
```

and check it if works fine. We don't know what file_get_html exactly does. Maybe it's causing problem

Comment: my script does `$html = file_get_html($url);` for remaining script execution it works fine

Comment: Ok, what's the $url variable content and if you remove this line the whole script works fine?

Comment: $url contains valid url name, rest of script work fine for sure

Comment: Ok, but what's the valid url? Does it begin with http:// and is it localhost ?

Comment: `echo $url;` and let us know the result.

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary `http://www.yelp.com` is the URL

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek please see URL in last comment

Comment: If you are running script on your localhost how come $url is yelp.com. Are you missing something or is it possible to share your code particularly 5-6 statements above and below the erring statement

Comment: I've changed answer. Please let us know if it's working fine. Also in your question there was file_get_contents and in comment you have file_get_html so finally we don't know what function you are using